# UIWebView AVPlayer Error

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios8, avplayer

I'm trying to make a video book in HTML/CSS/Javascript, pages are loaded in ajax (I have 10 pages). In each of this page there are 2 or 3 videos to illustrate.

On iOS7 everything works like a charm, the problem is on iOS8 after a while the videos stops working until I refresh the page. Following some exemple on this site I managed to make an observer to catch all events thrown. And what I found is this :

> 2014-11-27 10:16:30.658 ACDSM[840:331837] notification name: FailedToBecomeReadyForPlayback 
>   2014-11-27 10:16:30.659 ACDSM[840:331837] notification info: { Result = "-12983"; }

I have a -12983 error.

It seems to me that old videos are not released correctly or not released at all if I don't reload the page entirely.

What do you think? 
Is there a way to access the AVPlayer used by the UIWebView and to release all instances?

**EDIT :**

In addition when I pause the app, I see that a lot of thread  are in "com.apple.coremedia.player.async" in  semaphore_wait_trap .. from time to time those are terminated, when they are the videos starts working again. Is there a way to release them manualy ?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this since November or any updates? We are seeing the same sort of situation with semaphore_wait_trap when we play videos in the web view.

Comment: I haven't found any solution with UIWebView. The problem doesn't seems to be there when using the new WebkitWebview.